# silviomoreto / bootstrap-select / collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I use silviomoreto / bootstrap-select for select.
Here is  silviomoreto / bootstrap-select documentation: [silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

So I have a select and collaplsing block.

That block have to collapse by selecting any options in select.
For example : I choose any option then hidden block must appears.

```
<select class="selectpicker"  multiple title="Choose category">
    <option>House help</option>
    <option>Buy</option>
    <option>Drivers</option>
    <option>Holidays</option>
    <option>Animals</option>                                        
</select>   

<!-- HIDDEN BLOCK -->
<div class="hidden-input" id="hidden-input" style="display:none;">
    <div class="panel panel-default" >          
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">                
            <select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose subcategory">
                            <option>1</option>
            </select>   
        </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/8a2Vh/1/

**JS [extract]** :

```
$(".selectpicker").on('change', function(){
    $('#hidden-input').show().find('.collapse').collapse('show'); 
});
```